# Inverse of a Particular Matrix help R-{0}

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus

Let $$s\,=\,\left\{
\begin{bmatrix}
    a & a  \\
   a & a   
    \end{bmatrix}
  {\Big|}  a \in R- \{0\}\right\}$$ is a group under Matrix multiplication. Then find its inverse.

In a solution he says

Please help with how its identity is  $$I\,=\,
\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{2} &  \frac{1}{2}\\
    \frac{1}{2} &  \frac{1}{2}     
    \end{bmatrix}
 $$
I don't Know?

Please help on how to find its inverse it may be simple question

Comment: That isn't the identity.

Comment: Question Identity not given but in solution that is the identity told I don't know how

Comment: The identity of this group should have all of its entries equal to $1/3$ not $1/2$.

Comment: The "answers at the back of the book" are generally written as an afterthought and are often inaccurate. They are best taken with a pinch of salt.

Comment: Now that we are dealing with a group of $2 \times 2$ matrices instead of a group of $3 \times 3$ matrices, the identity is indeed the matrix with all entries equal to $1/2$. To show that it is the identity, you need to show that for any matrix $A \in s$, we have $IA = AI = A$.

Comment: How do i know that is the identity i am a little weak kind explain

Comment: I is not in the problem and inverse is asked

Answer (score 0):

By definition, the identity element of this group is the element $I$ such that $AI = IA = A$ for any element $A$ in the group. Then, the inverse of $A$ is the element of the group $B$ such that $AB = BA = I$.

Here, $I$ isn't $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$, which is the identity element in the group of all invertible $2 \times 2$ matrices.

Suppose that $I = \begin{bmatrix}c&c\\c&c\end{bmatrix}$ is the identity element. Then, for any $A = \begin{bmatrix}a&a\\a&a\end{bmatrix}$ we need

$$AI = IA = A$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}a&a\\a&a\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}c&c\\c&c\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}c&c\\c&c\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a&a\\a&a\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}a&a\\a&a\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}2ac&2ac\\2ac&2ac\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}2ac&2ac\\2ac&2ac\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}a&a\\a&a\end{bmatrix},$$

i.e. $2ac = a$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$.

The only value of $c$ which satisfies this condition is $c = \dfrac{1}{2}$, so the identity element is $I = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}$.

Now to find the inverse of $A$, note that if $B = \begin{bmatrix}b&b\\b&b\end{bmatrix}$ is the inverse of $A$, then $AB = BA = I$. Can you find the value of $b$ for which $AB = BA = I$ holds?